# android layout large image

Tags: android, android-layout, scaling

I have a large image myImage.png (its dims are 1536 x 784):

[image: Fig. 1]

I want this image to be placed at the bottom of my layout scaled uniformly and fitting the width:

[image: Fig. 2]

Layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/myImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried dozens of combinations for `layout_width`, `layout_height`, `adjustViewBounds` and `scaleType` and nothing helped: it always looks as follows:

[image: Fig. 3]

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone says, use src instead of background:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just tested and this solution works.
I noticed anyway that "android:scaleType does nothing", the trick is done using "android:adjustViewBounds"

Comment: Actually fitCenter keeps the image aspect ratio, fitXY stretch the image.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ImageView. ImageViews use the src attribute to indicate which image to use and to apply the scaleType to.

background, is, as name suggests, merely a background attribute, made to be displayed on that whole *background* thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/myImage"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scaleType="fitcenter" >
</ImageView>
```